# Order queryset using the number of related objects in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Let's say I have the following in **models.py**:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I want to do is sort a queryset for `A` based on how many `B` objects they have, in descending order. What is the best approach to this issue? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with a [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and then [**`.order_by(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
from django.db.models import Count

A.objects.annotate(
    nb=Count('b')
).order_by('-nb')
```

Since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2) you can work with [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) to prevent calculating this both as column and in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
from django.db.models import A

A.objects.alias(
    nb=Count('b')
).order_by('-nb')
```

Comment: Just one question. Shouldn't it be `Count("B")` because the name of the model is uppercase?

Comment: @darkhorse: no, the default `related_query_name` is the name of the model in *lowercase*. If you want to specify to a different one, you should set the `related_query_name=...` parameter in the `ForeignKey`, or the `related_name=...`.

Comment: Oh my mistake. What if the actual name for the model `B` was something like `ArticlePageView`? Would the statement then be `Count("articlepageview")`?

Comment: @darkhorse: yes, unless you have set the `related_query_name`, or `related_name` in the `ForeignKey` from `ArticlePageView` to `A`. If that is specified, it is the value you filled in for these parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is:

```
queryset = A.objects.filter().order_by('B_A')
```

Here **'B_A'** you have to put the related name

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'B_A')
```

Comment: This will not retrieve the `A` with the largest number of `B`s, it will retrieve (the same) `A` as many times as there are related `B` objects, and in ascending order of the primary key of `B`.